Segmentation fault when trying to resize a dynamic array of pointers
I've been learning some C++ for my uni courses, I've got a small but yet frustrating exercise to do. The user enters some numbers in the terminal, and it should add them to the array, when the array is full it should double in size, the rest of the 'positions' in the array should be null, however in my resize function I have an issue where it throws out a segmentation fault error.
The requirements that come with the exercise is that I have to use int** tab = new int*[size] and the indexes that aren't 'filled' with the user's input should be null.
MRE:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void resize(int**& tab, int& size) {
    int** new_tab = new int*[size * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        new_tab[i] = tab[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (tab[i] != nullptr)
            delete tab[i];
    }
    delete[] tab;
    tab = new_tab;
    size *= 2;
}

void add(int value, int** tab, int& size, int& count) {
    if (count == size)
        resize(tab, size);

    for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (tab[j])
            continue;

        tab[j] = new int;
        *tab[j] = value;
        break;
    }

    count++;
}

void print(int** tab, int size) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (tab[j] != nullptr)
            cout << *tab[j] << " ";
        else
            cout << "_ ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    int size = 4, count = 0, value;
    int** tab = new int*[size];

    do {
        cout << "> ";
        cin >> value;

        add(value, tab, size, count);
        print(tab, size);
    } while (value != 99);

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (tab[j] != nullptr)
            delete tab[j];
    }
    delete[] tab;

    return 0;
}

this is the 'error':


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There are three issues in your code that could cause segfaults:

You don't initialize any of the elements of your arrays.  By default, trivial objects in C++ are created with an indeterminate value, but your code assumes pointers will be initialized to nullptr.  If you want to value-initialize your array elements (which will initialize pointers to nullptr, add an extra set of {}:
int** new_tab = new int*[size * 2]{};
// -------------------------------^^ value-initialize

and
int** tab = new int*[size]{};
// -----------------------^^ value-initialize


In your resize function, you delete all of the ints that your pointers are pointing to:
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (tab[i] != nullptr)
        delete tab[i];

The pointers in new_tab point to those same ints, so after the function finishes you're left with an array full of dangling pointers.  You should remove that delete loop from your resize function.

You pass tab to add by value.  That means that the tab variable in add is a distinct object from the tab variable in main.  After add calls resize, the tab in main still has its old value, and points to the old, now-deleted array.  The easiest solution would be to pass tab by reference like you do in resize:
// ----------------------v Pass by reference
void add(int value, int**& tab, int& size, int& count) {



After fixing those issues the program runs successfully, though I suspect the result is still not what you want judging by those big gaps it leaves between the "used" array elements and the fact that the elements are in a different order than they were inserted.

This whole program seems overly-complex and brittle though.  There's no reason for every int to be dynamically-allocated.  That leads to lots of pointers to pointers, which are difficult to reason about.  Having 3 separate variables for tab, size, and count also makes things harder to handle.
To fix the first issue, you could simply use the current count to determine where to add the next value.  That would mean no need for null elements, and thus no extra level of pointers.
And to fix the second issue you could wrap the logic up into a class.  That way you have a single object that you can pass around instead of needing to pass around separate pointer, size, and count variables.
Putting those together could look something like this:
#include <iostream>

class IntVec {
public:
    IntVec(int capacity)
        : data_{new int[capacity]},
          capacity_{capacity},
          count_{0}
    {}
    
    // Disable copying to avoid having multiple objects hold pointers to the same array.
    // TODO: Implement proper copy logic that copies the contents of the array.
    IntVec(const IntVec&) = delete;
    IntVec& operator=(const IntVec&) = delete;
    
    ~IntVec()
    {
        delete[] data_;
    }
    
    void add(int value)
    {
        if (count_ == capacity_) {
            resize();
        }
        
        data_[count_++] = value;
    }
    
    int& operator[](int i)
    {
        return data_[i];
    }
    
    const int& operator[](int i) const
    {
        return data_[i];
    }
    
    int count() const
    {
        return count_;
    }
    
private:
    void resize()
    {
        int new_capacity = capacity_ * 2;
        int* new_data = new int[new_capacity];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < count_; ++i) {
            new_data[i] = data_[i];
        }
        
        delete[] data_;
        data_ = new_data;
        capacity_ = new_capacity;
    }
    
    int* data_;
    int capacity_;
    int count_;
};

void print(const IntVec& tab) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tab.count(); j++) {
        std::cout << tab[j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    IntVec tab{4};

    int value = 99;
    do {
        std::cout << "> ";
        std::cin >> value;

        tab.add(value);
        print(tab);
    } while (value != 99);
}

Demo

Of course, for any real program you should just use std::vector instead of rolling your own:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print(const std::vector<int>& tab) {
    for (int i : tab) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> tab;

    int value = 99;
    do {
        std::cout << "> ";
        std::cin >> value;

        tab.push_back(value);
        print(tab);
    } while (value != 99);
}

Demo
